# sony vaio tap 11 touchpad and mouse conflict

Tags: mouse, touchpad, vaio

I have a question, which I have a partial answer to, but would like to have a full answer. And my partial answer might be helpful to others.

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Sony Vaio Tap 11, and everything works fine, until I touch the touchpad. After that, the mouse left click doesn't work any more. Mouse (I have a bluetooth Microsoft Sculpt Mouse) and touchpad. So basically I am left without means of left-clicking, other than touching the screen, which still works.

Good news is that if you don't touch the touchpad, everything works fine. And since I do have a bluetooth mouse, I just turned off the touchpad (there is a key for that in the keyboard/touchpad combo).

But, I'd like to fix that, since having a touchpad is useful. So, does anyone know anything about this bug ?

And, of course, I am posting this to tell others with the same problem to switch off the touchpad, it took me several days to figure it out.

Thanks,
           Sergio.

Comment: Sergio, thanks for reporting. I have the same problem. Haven't managed to find any solution so far….